# Can you create trial shorter than subscription period in PayPal?

Tags: paypal

Can you create trial shorter than subscription period in PayPal?
Say, subscription period is 1 month and make trial 2 weeks.
It looks possible, but is it really on practice?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, we do this, the subscription is monthly and the trials are weekly.

Easy enough to test in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for PayPal Subscription button with period 1 month and trial 2 weeks.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR PAYPAL ACOUNT MERCHANT ID">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="C2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test_sub">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="W">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

---

For the more information about PayPal Subscription button, you can refer to the link below.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_step_1/